# F#- AsyncSeq - how to return values in a list

Tags: asynchronous, f#, functional-programming

Attempting to find anagrams in a list of words using F Sharps Async Sequences (I am aware there are better algorithms for anagram finding but trying to understand Async Sequneces)

From  the 'runTest' below how can I 
1. async read the collecion returned and output to screen
2. block until all results return & display final count/collection

```
  open System
    open System.ServiceModel
    open System.Collections.Generic
    open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq
    open FSharp.Control

    [<Literal>]
    let testWord = "table"

    let testWords =  new List<string>()
    testWords.Add("bleat")
    testWords.Add("blate")
    testWords.Add("junk")


    let hasWord (word:string) =    
        let mutable res = true
        let a = testWord.ToCharArray()  |> Set.ofArray
        let b = word.ToCharArray()  |> Set.ofArray
        let difference = Set.intersect a b
        match difference.Count with
        | 0 ->  false
        | _ ->  true 

    let test2 (words:List<string>, (word:string)) : AsyncSeq<string>  =
        asyncSeq   {
                        let res =
                                (words)
                                |> Seq.filter(fun x-> (hasWord(x)) )
                                |>  AsyncSeq.ofSeq                                                  
                        yield! res
                }

    let runTest = test2(testWords,testWord) 
                                            |> //pull stuff from stream
                                            |> // output to screen   
                                            |> ignore              

    ()
```

Comment: Are you aware that more traditional indentation is only 4 spaces more than the previous line>

Comment: yeh - this is the result from moving stuff around - will clean up the end result - curious as to how to read data pulled from the sequence - PS is there an online F# formatter?

Comment: just reformatted the code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as you have the `test2` function returning an asyncSeq.  Your questions:

> **1. async read the collecion returned and output to screen**

If you want to have some side-effecting code (such as outputting to the screen) you can use `AsyncSeq.iter` to apply a function to each item as it becomes available. Iter returns an `Async<unit>` so you can then "kick it off" using an appropriate Async method (blocking/non-blocking).

For example:

```
let processItem i = 
    // Do whatever side effecting code you want to do with an item
    printfn "Item is '%s'" i

let runTestQ1 = 
    test2 (testWords, testWord) 
    |> AsyncSeq.iter processItem 
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

> **2. block until all results return & display final count/collection**

If you want all the results collected so that you can work on them together, then you can convert the AsyncSeq into a normal Seq using `AsyncSeq.toBlockingSeq` and then convert it to a list to force the Seq to evaluate.

For example:

```
let runTestQ2 = 
    let allResults = 
        test2 (testWords, testWord) 
        |> AsyncSeq.toBlockingSeq 
        |> Seq.toList
    // Do whatever you would like with your list of results
    printfn "Final list is '%A' with a count of %i" allResults (allResults.Length)
```

Comment: Thanks - fixed gist is here using an observer https://gist.github.com/chrismckelt/d9d113edc3d3bf4afe91